# Camera Launching cancelled.Camera app

Tags: android, xml, button, null, camera

Hey I am new to android and eclipse environment.I've no idea of Java.I'm trying to create an app to open the camera of an android device.This is how my main activity.java looks like

```
package com.example.trycamera2;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private Uri fileUri;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);*****
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xray");
              dir.mkdirs();
             File file = new File(dir, "tmp_avatar_"
                              + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
              fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
             intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
             startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
    });
};
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap tempBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(fileUri.getPath());
                tempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v("ManageImage-other", "another phone type"); 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
    }

}
```

There is a red mark under button_send in the star marked line...it shows an alternative action_settings instead of button_send....but when I replace with action_settings and run the launch is cancelled.Failed to install .apk on emulator..any help will be of great use.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Android can't find your button in any of the layouts.  Double check your layouts to make sure they're there.

If they are, just go to the Project menu at the top, and select Clean.  Select your project, then click Okay.  It will take moment to clean and build, but that might fix your issue.